# Using http remote MD5 hash

Tags: shell-script, arch-linux, hashsum, pkgbuild

I would like to use the md5sums function of [pkgbuild](/questions/tagged/pkgbuild) without keeping track of new [hashsum](/questions/tagged/hashsum) at each update, and just change the pkgver variable to build a new version of my package.

`md5` are available on the [official website](http://php.net/downloads.php) of the project i'm interested in near the source archive download in a span of `class` value of `md5sum`

As I know the [hashsum](/questions/tagged/hashsum) will always be in a `span` of `class` `md5sum` right after the `span` of `class` `releasedate` , itself behind two `a href` having `tar.xz` in them, how can I extract the [hashsum](/questions/tagged/hashsum) from the [website](http://php.net/downloads.php) using a shell script that may call tools usually preinstalled on an [archlinux](/questions/tagged/archlinux) installation into a variable that will strictly contain only the [hashsum](/questions/tagged/hashsum) ?

Comment: Have you seen the sections of the [PKGBUILD documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PKGBUILD#source) about signatures and integrity?  That project includes `.asc` signatures, so you can use those for validation and skip the checksum step altogether.

Comment: You can just set the value of the checksum for a file to `SKIP` and makepkg will not try to verify the checksum of that file.

Comment: @JigglyNaga indeed, but that would still be useful to learn how it could be done.

Comment: @Wieland Cannot guarantee the download won't screw up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are intent on scraping the hash off the page, then something like this will work.  It's the sort of one-liner I write for one-off use, because it's likely to break as soon as the layout changes:

```
hashsum=$(curl http://php.net/downloads.php |
 grep -A1 -F ">php-${pkgver}.tar.xz<" |
 sed 1d |
 tr '>' '<' |
 cut -d '<' -f3 )
```

---

To understand why this is an incredibly inflexible approach, it may help to look at the output of each stage.

- `curl` fetches the page and sends it to the standard output.  (If you don't have `curl` available, `wget -O -` will also work.)

  The output includes this:

  ```
  ...
  <ul>
            <li>
        <a href="/get/php-7.0.7.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror">php-7.0.7.tar.bz2</a> <a href="/get/php-7.0.7.tar.bz2.asc/from/a/mirror">(sig)</a> [13,776Kb]          <span class="releasedate">26 May 2016</span>
        <span class="md5sum">cc231de15146ca14a69610f695995ab8</span>
        <span class="sha256">474f2925c4782b94016e3afbb17b14ff9cc6f4fdb6f6e231b36a378bb18a3d1a</span>
                </li>
            <li>
        <a href="/get/php-7.0.7.tar.gz/from/a/mirror">php-7.0.7.tar.gz</a> <a href="/get/php-7.0.7.tar.gz.asc/from/a/mirror">(sig)</a> [17,792Kb]          <span class="releasedate">26 May 2016</span>
        <span class="md5sum">197ec66d134da8968ddd0b89f1cfac2a</span>
        <span class="sha256">66282ff4a9f88fe9607d9574e15bf335885b964245591a1740adb3f79c514a67</span>
                </li>
            <li>
        <a href="/get/php-7.0.7.tar.xz/from/a/mirror">php-7.0.7.tar.xz</a> <a href="/get/php-7.0.7.tar.xz.asc/from/a/mirror">(sig)</a> [11,219Kb]          <span class="releasedate">26 May 2016</span>
        <span class="md5sum">75f8d1693a470cefe2a50abd283eb291</span>
        <span class="sha256">9cc64a7459242c79c10e79d74feaf5bae3541f604966ceb600c3d2e8f5fe4794</span>
                </li>
          <li>
      <a href="http://windows.php.net/download#php-7.0">
        Windows downloads
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  ...
  ```
- `grep -A1` returns the line containing that pattern (the name of the source file you need), plus 1 line following it:

  ```
    <a href="/get/php-7.0.7.tar.xz/from/a/mirror">php-7.0.7.tar.xz</a> <a href="/get/php-7.0.7.tar.xz.asc/from/a/mirror">(sig)</a> [11,219Kb]          <span class="releasedate">26 May 2016</span>
    <span class="md5sum">75f8d1693a470cefe2a50abd283eb291</span>
  ```
- We only care about the second line, so `sed 1d` deletes the first.  (If you want to be sure it's an md5sum, use `grep 'class="md5sum"'` instead.)

  ```
    <span class="md5sum">75f8d1693a470cefe2a50abd283eb291</span>
  ```
- The `tr` command turns all `>` to `<`.  This is not useful on its own, but turns the line into something that `cut` can work with:

  ```
    <span class="md5sum"<75f8d1693a470cefe2a50abd283eb291</span<
  ```
- Finally, `cut` treats those `<`s (including the ones that were previously `>`s) as delimiters, and extracts the 3rd item, ie. the hash:

  ```
  75f8d1693a470cefe2a50abd283eb291
  ```

Comment: It works but it doesn't seem to look specifically for a span of class md5sum, is it because it is not possible or is it because it was simpler this way ? What about resilience to small changes then ?

Comment: @Zulgrib Purely for simplicity/laziness.  I'll add some notes about what each step does.